# Agda Error message : Cannot eliminate type with variable pattern

Tags: agda, isomorphism

I was asked to finish one of the recommended question from [plfa](https://plfa.github.io/Connectives/):

```
Exercise ⇔≃× (recommended)
Show that A ⇔ B as defined earlier is isomorphic to (A → B) × (B → A).
```

I know I need to prove some property of equivalence first, and here is my proof:

```
record _⇔_ (A B : Set) : Set where
    field
      to   : A → B
      from : B → A
  ⇔-refl : ∀ {A : Set} → A ⇔ A
  ⇔-refl =
    record
      { to      = λ{x → x}
      ; from    = λ{y → y}
      }
  ⇔-sym : ∀ {A B : Set}
     → A ⇔ B 
     → B ⇔ A 
  ⇔-sym A⇔B =
    record
      { to = _⇔_.from A⇔B
      ; from = _⇔_.to A⇔B
      }
  ⇔-trans : ∀ {A B C : Set}
     → A ⇔ B
     → B ⇔ C
     → A ⇔ C
  ⇔-trans A⇔B B⇔C =
    record
      { to = (_⇔_.to B⇔C) ∘ (_⇔_.to A⇔B )
      ; from = (_⇔_.from A⇔B) ∘ (_⇔_.from B⇔C )
      }
```

And now, from my understanding, I need to prove
`⇔≃× : ∀ {A B : Set} → A ⇔ B ≃ (A → B) × (B → A)`
So to prove this, we need to prove four sections: "to" "from" "from∘to" "to∘from"

```
⇔≃× : ∀ {A B : Set} → (A ⇔ B) ≃ ((A → B) × (B → A))
⇔≃× =
    record
      { to = λ{ x ⇔ y → ⟨ ( x → y )  , ( y → x ) ⟩ }
      ; from = ?
      ; from∘to = ?
      ; to∘from = ?
      }
```

But when I finish the "to" section, I want to see if it can pass. So I compile and  I got this error message:

```
Cannot eliminate type (A → B) × (B → A) with variable pattern ⇔(did you supply too many arguments?)when checking the clause left hand side.extendedlambda2 x ⇔ y
```

Can anyone give some explanation on this type of error message?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`λ{ x ⇔ y →` binds three arguments: `x`, `⇔`, and `y` but the function you're supposed to define only takes one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply first!! So, from my understanding, Agda can work implicitly, right, which means x and y in my case stands for A and B, respectively. So, according to your answer, I think I should think of (x ⇔ y) as a whole, so I need to add a bracket in my code : to = λ{ (x ⇔ y) → ⟨ (x → y) , (y → x) ⟩}, but it seems that it still doesn't work.... And here is the error message: Could not parse the left-hand side .extendedlambda2 (x ⇔ y)
Problematic expression: ((x ⇔) y)

Comment: What? No. `A` and `B` are (implicitly) bound on the LHS of the  definition of `⇔≃×`.